# Excellentexport xlsx support

Tags: javascript, excellentexport

I am using [Excellent Export](https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport) plugin to export my html table to xls excel file, and it is working great but I want to export my table to xlsx instead. Is there any support for that?

I think it should be doable by changing

```
var uri = {excel: 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,', csv: 'data:application/csv;base64,'};
var template = {excel: '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'};
```

But not sure how to do this.

Or is there any other easy way to export multiple tables into one excel sheet (xlsx)?

Comment: Does anyone got any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You must upgrade to 3.0.0 (22/10/2017) issue. It have XLSX support.